# Unable to to load web page in chrome (due to DDoS projection by cloudflare)

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

The website i was trying to automate is having "DoS projection by cloudflare". Here is my code.

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("start-maximized");
    options.addArguments("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled");
    options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
    options.addArguments("--profile-directory=Default");
    options.addArguments("--disable-plugins-discovery");
    options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", new String[]{"enable-automation"});
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.get(url);
```

But I am unable to load the website. Can anyone suggest the fix.

Comment: Could it be that you're hitting the website too fast/too often and thus get blocked as a potential DDoS attacker?

Comment: @Thomas      ,  I don't think issue is due to hitting website too fast/ often, because I got this problem at  the very first time itself with providing wait time for the page. Here the website I tried (https://www.autocodes.com/).